# Local .bashrc is not read on startup under MobaXterm Home on Windows

Tags: windows, bash, cygwin

I am using **MobaXTerm (Home version 3.0)**. I have create a direcorty `C:\MobaXterm_3.0\home` and set in the local configuration (Settings --> Configuration) the home directory to this path. Under this path I have created a `.bashrc` file with read access for everybody.

**However when starting up MobaXterm, the `.bashrc` file does not get executed.** How can I fix this? The MobaXterm docu says that in the Home addition I cannot change the `/etc/profile`, but the standard `/etc/profile` does execute ~/.bashrc. So I am a bit at a loss.

ps: I am aware of the [answer to "How does one define aliases for use within MobaXTerm *local* bash shell?"](https://superuser.com/a/1021523) and have created the `.bashrc` file with the right permissions.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When you launch a local terminal in MobaXterm first time `.bash_profile` is executed which sets up the required configuration for the initial shell command prompt to work. The idea is to source the `.bashrc` from the `.bash_profile`.

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
   source ~/.bashrc
fi
```

Add the above lines to your `.bash_profile`.

Source:                                http://www.joshstaiger.org/archives/2005/07/bash_profile_vs.html

Comment: The question was about **local** terminal, not ssh terminal. But the solution works! So I have filed an edit to the answer.